# How do I use the 'Filebrowser' module?

Tags: 7

I have installed/enabled the [Filebrowser](https://www.drupal.org/project/filebrowser) (v 7.24) module and set permissions...

It is said to provide ftp style file browsing capabilities, but I can't find any way of invoking it.

I am used to installing and getting modules working, and I have read the sparse documentation which refers to it as a node, but I can find no way to create a node or navigate to a page that is anything like the screenshot.

There are no new content types, nothing changed on creating new content, nothing new appears under any of the admin menus, appending filebrowser and variations to my site's URL does nothing.

How to open file browsing window?

Comment: Interesting edit Molot

Comment: We are trying to maintain high standard of language here. I'm not the best, but I was able to make it more straight to the point.

Answer (score 1):

I could be going blind or it could have been a page refresh that was needed...

You create a new node and select "create a new directory listing"

Really straight-forward...

Comment: I was about to post answer starting with *"If there are no new content types for you, you encountered a bug. This module defines new content type, with machine name `dir_listing`"*. I see it is no longer needed. Cache clear and page reload is **always** first thing to try.

Comment: Yes, I've used this module and was about to post a comment like 'what @Mołot mentioned above.